# ICustomDestinationList windows7 taskbar feature

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, tasklist

I am looking for the windows7 ICustomDestinationList implementation using typelibrary.
Can anyone please provide an idl defenition or tlb typelibrary ..?

Answer (score 1):

shobjidl.idl from the [Windows 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=C17BA869-9671-4330-A63E-1FD44E0E2505&displaylang=en) should do the trick...